# Group chat iMessages now being received through email

Tags: mac, messages

I'm in a group chat with my friends and all of a sudden one of my friends text messages now go to my email (I use my iCloud email for iMessage). It's from an email address *******705@vzwpix.com and the other people in the group chat have their phone numbers as email addresses. How do I fix this? Is this a problem on my end or my friend's end?

Comment: did you change the email address registered with iMessage lately?

Comment: I added another email address 3 months ago @JBRWilkinson

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Someone's phone decided to switch to SMS or MMS, as evidenced by the `@vzwpix.com` return address—this is a domain used by providers to gateway SMS/MMS to/from email.

I routinely run into a similar issue when attempting group messaging with people with phones from other manufacturers, but it's also conceivable an iPhone may choose to do this if it cannot access iMessage temporarily, e.g. if there was no data connection available.

To prevent this, it's probably best to use an entirely different chat service rather than try to match up the disparate capabilities of phones.